# Shell and page initialization

Tags: c#, maui

I have the following xaml code

```
<Shell
    x:Class="ControlBarcos.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ControlBarcos.Views"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlBarcos"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">
     <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior IsEnabled="True" IsVisible="True"/>
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>

    <Shell.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.2*,0.8*">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                       Margin="5"
                       HeightRequest="25"
                       WidthRequest="25"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Title}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       FontSize="Large"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center" /> 
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:InicialPage}" />
    <FlyoutItem Title="Barcos"
                Icon="shipdos.png">
       <Tab>
           <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:VerBarcosPage}" />
       </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Empresas Externas"
                Icon="humano.png">
       <Tab>
           <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:VerEmpresasPage}" />
       </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
</Shell>
```

The InicialPage is page just showing a logo.
When I select the menu option "Barcos"  the first time  "VerBarcosPage" constructor gets called, but when the option is selected again the constructor is not called. I would need the constructor to always be called. Any ideas on how I can force the constructor to always be called?
The code for VerBarcosPage is:

public partial class VerBarcosPage : ContentPage
{
public VerBarcosViewModel viewModel;

```
public VerBarcosPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    viewModel = new VerBarcosViewModel();
    BindingContext = viewModel;

}
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a known issue on GitHub : [Shell, Navigation and Page instantiation](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9300). And when you navigate pages using shell, the page instance will not be created now.

You may tried the [workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9300#issuecomment-1416893792) posted by @PureWeen. Just override [OnNavigated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.shell.onnavigated?view=xamarin-forms) method in AppShell,

```
protected override void OnNavigated(ShellNavigatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigated(args);
    if (CurrentItem?.CurrentItem?.CurrentItem is not null &&
        _previousShellContent is not null)
    {
        var property = typeof(ShellContent)
            .GetProperty("ContentCache", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

        property.SetValue(_previousShellContent, null);
    }

    _previousShellContent = CurrentItem?.CurrentItem?.CurrentItem;
}
```

I've tested and the page's constructor will fire again.